# How to install Pocket Island Open Source Application?

Tags: ruby

I have no idea with Ruby Language.

I just want to install and try Pocket Island Open Source.

```
git://github.com/wooga/Pocket-Island.git
```

What are the requirement and how to run it? I'm using Ubuntu Desktop. If possible, Please guide step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [README.md](https://github.com/wooga/Pocket-Island/blob/master/README.md) for the project to determine what is required and how to run it.